# Why can't I work with matrices of images?

Tags: matlab

What is wrong with the following function?

```
function draw_multiple_images(image_list)    
    d = size(image_list);
    l = length(d);

        figure;
        hold all

        N = d(3) ;
        [m, n] = factor_out(N);
        for k=1:N
            I = image_list(:,:,k);
            size(I)
            h = subplot(m,n,k);
            image(I,'Parent',h);
            set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
        end  
    hold off
end
```

**Error Message**

```
Error using image
Invalid datatype for Image CData. Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData.

Error in draw_multiple_images (line 11)
            image(I,'Parent',h);

Error in draw_multiple_images_test (line 17)
    draw_multiple_images(bp_filter_out_image);
```

Comment: What is image_list? What is it's class? What are it's dimensions?

Comment: Error clearly says image needs numbers or logical...which shows input is not a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I used `imshow` in place of `image`.

```
N = d(3) ;
[m, n] = factor_out(N);
for k=1:N
    I = image_list(:,:,k);
    subplot(m,n,k);
    imshow(I);
    set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
end
```